# plot Buy ratio as a function of the time spent on an item in a session, session duration and the number of clicks on a given item in a session

Tags: r, histogram

I have a dataframe with 34154695 obs. In a dataset a Class variable with value 0 indicate "not purchased" and 1 indicate "purchase".

```
> str(data)
'data.frame':   34154695 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ SessionID: int  1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 ...
 $ Timestamp: Factor w/ 34069144 levels "2014-04-01T03:00:00.124Z",..: 1452469 1452684 1453402 1501801 1501943 1502207 1502429 1502569 1502932 295601 ...
 $ ItemID   : int  214536500 214536506 214577561 214662742 214662742 214825110 214757390 214757407 214551617 214716935 ...
 $ Category : Factor w/ 339 levels "0","1","10","11",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Class    : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

where as the number of sessions are

```
> length(unique(data$SessionID)) 
[1] 9249729


> head(data, 50)
   SessionID                Timestamp    ItemID Category Class
1          1 2014-04-07T10:54:09.868Z 214536500        0     0
2          1 2014-04-07T10:54:46.998Z 214536506        0     0
3          1 2014-04-07T10:57:00.306Z 214577561        0     0
4          2 2014-04-07T13:56:37.614Z 214662742        0     0
5          2 2014-04-07T13:57:19.373Z 214662742        0     0
6          2 2014-04-07T13:58:37.446Z 214825110        0     0
7          2 2014-04-07T13:59:50.710Z 214757390        0     0
8          2 2014-04-07T14:00:38.247Z 214757407        0     0
9          2 2014-04-07T14:02:36.889Z 214551617        0     0
10         3 2014-04-02T13:17:46.940Z 214716935        0     0
11         3 2014-04-02T13:26:02.515Z 214774687        0     0
12         3 2014-04-02T13:30:12.318Z 214832672        0     0
13         4 2014-04-07T12:09:10.948Z 214836765        0     0
14         4 2014-04-07T12:26:25.416Z 214706482        0     0
15         6 2014-04-06T16:58:20.848Z 214701242        0     0
16         6 2014-04-06T17:02:26.976Z 214826623        0     0
17         7 2014-04-02T06:38:53.104Z 214826835        0     0
18         7 2014-04-02T06:39:05.854Z 214826715        0     0
19         8 2014-04-06T08:49:58.728Z 214838855        0     0
20         8 2014-04-06T08:52:12.647Z 214838855        0     0
21         9 2014-04-06T11:26:24.127Z 214576500        0     0
22         9 2014-04-06T11:28:54.654Z 214576500        0     0
23         9 2014-04-06T11:29:13.479Z 214576500        0     0
24        11 2014-04-03T10:44:35.672Z 214821275        0     0
25        11 2014-04-03T10:45:01.674Z 214821275        0     0
26        11 2014-04-03T10:45:29.873Z 214821371        0     0
27        11 2014-04-03T10:46:12.162Z 214821371        0     0
28        11 2014-04-03T10:46:57.355Z 214821371        0     0
29        11 2014-04-03T10:53:22.572Z 214717089        0     0
30        11 2014-04-03T10:53:49.875Z 214563337        0     0
31        11 2014-04-03T10:55:19.267Z 214706462        0     0
32        11 2014-04-03T10:55:47.327Z 214717436        0     0
33        11 2014-04-03T10:56:30.520Z 214743335        0     0
34        11 2014-04-03T10:57:19.331Z 214826837        0     0
35        11 2014-04-03T10:57:39.433Z 214819762        0     0
36        12 2014-04-02T10:30:13.176Z 214717867        0     0
37        12 2014-04-02T10:33:12.621Z 214717867        0     0
38        13 2014-04-06T14:50:13.638Z 214836761        0     0
39        13 2014-04-06T14:52:54.363Z 214684513        0     0
40        13 2014-04-06T14:53:18.268Z 214836761        0     0
41        14 2014-04-01T10:09:01.362Z 214577732        0     0
42        14 2014-04-01T10:11:14.773Z 214587013        0     0
43        14 2014-04-01T10:12:36.482Z 214577732        0     0
44        17 2014-04-06T11:34:14.289Z 214826897        0     0
45        17 2014-04-06T11:34:16.193Z 214820441        0     0
46        16 2014-04-05T13:08:01.626Z 214684093        0     0
47        16 2014-04-05T13:08:39.897Z 214684093        0     0
48        16 2014-04-05T13:20:53.092Z 214684093        0     0
49        19 2014-04-01T20:52:12.357Z 214561790        0     0
50        19 2014-04-01T20:52:13.758Z 214561790        0     0
```

i want to plot Buy ratio as a function of the time spent on an item in a session, the number of clicks on a given item in a session and the session’s duration.i wanna output like this
[image]

[image]

[image]
Could someone please inform how I should proceed?? Really, thank you for any help and suggesting.

Kind regards

Comment: Hello, please provide sample data using `dput(head(mydata,20))`.

Comment: ok sir see the edited question

Comment: Please provide your expected outcome by taking your data for example.

Comment: ok sir see the edited question